# Recursion wrong output

Tags: java, loops, recursion, methods

I am given the following code

```
int go(int x){
   if (x<1)
      return 1;
   else
      return x + go(x-2) + go(x-3);
}
```

The answer is `7` by calling `go(3)`but everytime I do it (I have to do it by hand) I get 8. This is my logic:

3 + go(1) + go(0)/1 = 3 + go(1) + 1(because 0 is less than 1)

Then,

3 + go(-1) = 3 + 1

Therefore,

3 + 4 + 1 = 8.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To the code that I wrote on the question

Comment: Where did `3 + go(-1)` come from?

Comment: Where did 4 come from?

Comment: Are you calculating for x = 3?

Comment: JavaB probably used x=3 for the go(1) call and got "3+go(-1)"

Comment: Yes, I just added it to the question. It is calculating for x=3

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 Then `go(x-3)` went somewhere...

Comment: correct. go(-2) went for a walk somewhere.

Comment: I got it now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you made mistake as `go(1) = 3 + go(1-2)` where the actual formula is `go(1) = 1 + go(1-2) + go(1-3)`.

```
  go(3)
= 3 + go(1) + go(0)
= 3 + go(1) + 1
= 3 + (1 + go(-1) + go(-2)) + 1
= 3 + (1 + 1 + 1) + 1
= 7
```

Comment: I do not understand how you got "(1 + go(-1) + go(-2)) ".. Sorry I am new at this

Comment: nvm, I got it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
go(3)

3 + go(3-2) + go(3-3)

3 + go(1) + go(0)

3 + 1 + go(1-2) + go(1-3) + 1

5 + go(-1) + go(-2)

5 + 1 + 1

7
```

Comment: Where did you get "1 + go(1-2) + go(1-3) " from? Sorry if my question is dumb, I am a beginner

Comment: nvm, I got it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
answer is 7 which is correct. 

3 + go(3-2) + go(3-3) 
 = 3 + go(1) + go(0)

 go(0) = 1 

 go(1) = 1 + go(1-2) + go ( 1-3)
       = 1 + go(-1) + go(-2)
       = 1 + 1 + 1 
       = 3 


 = putting all values go(3) = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

in this recursive method, your base case is `x<1`, so whenever that is the case 1 will be returned.

The following is how it will be played out.

```
go(3)== 3 + 3 + 1 == 7
 3 + go(3-2)=>go(1) + go(3-3)=>go(0)
  go(1)==1+1+1==3
    1 + go(1-2)=>go(-1) + go(1-3)=>go(-2)
      go(-1)==1
        1
      go(-2)==1
        1
  go(0)==1
    1
```

Hope the structure shows how it will be played out. If anything, always try doing out the branches a recursive method creates